# Run a script at specified time in linux

Tags: cron, webdriver

I have created scripts and now I want them to run automatically at specified time, how can I do that?

I am using Ubuntu and JAVA to write my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crontab` to do this in a specific time continuously.

To edit a crontab entries, Login as root user (su – root) and do crontab -e as shown below. By default this will edit the current logged-in users crontab.

```
root@dev-db# crontab -e
```

**Scheduling a Job For a Specific Time**

> The basic usage of cron is to execute a job in a specific time as
>   shown below. This will execute the Full backup shell script
>   (full-backup) on 10th June 08:30 AM.

Please note that the time field uses 24 hours format. So, for 8 AM use 8, and for 8 PM use 20.

```
30 08 10 06 * /home/ramesh/full-backup
```

More example [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/), and the crontab utils can be found [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/crontab-command/)

Comment: I have no idea on cron jobs, please can you guide , how I can set that up and running?

Comment: @User2172723: `crontab` suits for your requirement, Check my edited answer.